# installing an app shell for my angular4 app

Tags: javascript, angular, app-shell

I've seen many articles online about the app shell and how it's used but it just doesn't seem to work for me following a very clear article from [Angular Universirty](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-app-shell/) I got the following error

```js
C:\projects\NoddlesHub>ng generate app-shell my-loading-shell  --universal-app=ngu-app-shell  --route=app-shell-path
Error: Chunk cannot be found.
Chunk cannot be found.
```

And most of the other tutorials always require a --mobile when creating the angular app from the beginning. I'll be grateful if I can get a very recent and helpful info about rendering the app shell

Comment: also facing a similar issue while running the same command from their blog post.

Comment: I can't really remember how I got passed the error.